# How export VAR to another script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

How i can export this vars to another script. The other scrit need run to run some commands . I want that because the script is too big and i want to split it and put the var in another script

```
# Ficheiros onde serão guardados as palavras passes e os nomes do utilizadores
password_list="$HOME/passwords.txt" 
user_list="$HOME/users.txt" 
newpassword_list="$HOME/newuserpassword.txt" 
# MAIL
DESTINATARIO="mail"
ENVIADOPOR="mail"
ASSUNTO="Palavra passe, utilizadores, hostname"
# SSHPASS
run1="sshpass -p $oldpass ssh host@ip"
run2="sshpass -p $newpassword ssh host@ip"
run3="sshpass -p $oldpass ssh host@ip"
run4="sshpass -p $newpassword ssh host@ip"
run5="sshpass -p $oldpass ssh redmine@ip"
run6="sshpass -p $newpassword ssh redmine@ip"
```

Comment: uhh, have you looked into `export` at all?

Comment: You'll want to use `set -a` to auto-export variables, and the `source` command... Actually, you don't need to export them, the script with the code just needs to source the script with the variables.

Comment: What variables do you want to export? What's the problem with doing it? What command do you want to export them to? The snippet you posted doesn't seem to run any external commands, it just sets some variables. Could you rewrite the comments in English, as that would make them easier to understand for most of use. Or just remove them, if they're not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To basically answer your question, the "export" keyword before variable assignment will make if available to all sub-shells you'll run, example:

```
export DESTINATARIO="mail"
```

Howerver, if the reason is that your script is "too big", you may also consider organizing your shell scripts into libraries, with a top script calling functions in included files. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# load functions defined in mylib1.sh and mylib2.sh
source mylib1.sh
source mylib2.sh
# set my var
VAR1=123abc
# call functions from mylib1.sh and mylib2.sh
lib1func1 $VAR1
lib2func2 $VAR1
```

Having for example in mylib1.sh the function definition of lib1func1:

```
lib1func1() {
  local firstvar=$1    # reading 
  echo $firstvar
}
```

Of course, the top shell can also export variables (globals) that the libraries will know, but I would not encvourage this way, since it is less modular.

Comment: Just to be complete, it should be mentioned that if you run a script that has an `export` in it, when the script terminates, you will not have the variable set. To have it kept after the script terminates, you need instead to source the script.